# MPChart: x axis couldn't display date completely

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have a problem using MPChart ：
   x axis couldn't display the first date，could someone help me？thanks！

[image]

Comment: What do you pass in Entry as x value? unix timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `setAvoidFirstLastClipping(Boolean)` from your chart to avoid your first and last labels to be truncated.

From the doc:

> setAvoidFirstLastClipping(boolean enabled): If set to true, the chart will avoid that the first and last axis label entry in the x-axis "clip" off the edge of the chart or the screen.